Enabling/disabling notifications using React Native - Notifee
Recently i started work with notifications and faced a challenge to enabling / disabling push notifications with notifee. Here's my code:
useEffect(() => {
    void createNotifeeChannel();
    console.log('Notifications are enabled??: ', notificationsEnabled);

    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(
      async (remoteMessage: FirebaseMessagingTypes.RemoteMessage) => {
        if (notificationsEnabled) {
          await notifee.requestPermission({
            provisional: true,
          });
          displayNotification(remoteMessage);
        }
      },
    );

    return unsubscribe;
}, [notificationsEnabled]);

I tried implementing enable / disable notifications with useState - notificationsEnabled. But notificationsEnabled inside onMessage callback doesn't change. Why and what's wrong??

onMessage is for receiving a message in the foreground. Take a look at the documentation on how to setup for the client: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client.
